# How to implement an efficient view of a List?

Tags: java, list

I need a class `HidingList` implementing a view of a `List` where for each element in the original there's a bit saying if it should be included in the view. The simple solution is to use a `BitSet`, however I see no simple and efficient way how to implement `hidingList.get(int index)` in case the list gets big. Something like

```
public T get(int index) {
    int realIndex = bitSet.nextSetBit(0);
    for (int i=0; i<index; ++i) {
        realIndex = bitSet.nextSetBit(realIndex+1);
    }
    return delegate.get(realIndex);
}
```

doesn't look terribly efficient and I can't see a method like `bitSet.cardinality(int from, int to)`. Maybe there's already something like I need in Guava or somewhere?

Comment: There's none in Guava precisely because the view would have a very poor performance. See http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/issues/detail?id=505

Comment: You could maintain a `List<List>` containing all the sublists of delegate that constitute the retained items (subList is a view, not a copy). You could then iterate over the subList.size() until you find the correct sublist and get the relevant item from that sublist (and/or store the results in a NavigableMap for efficiency).

Comment: @JB Nizet: That's a bit different. Filtering a `List` by an arbitrary `Predicate` can't be any better than what `Iterables.filter` return. However, here I'm having some slowly changing bits instead of a general `Predicate`.

Comment: @assylias: This would work nicely in case there are only few such sublists. With every second element hidden it'd get really big and slow.

Answer (score 0):

If you want `get(int)` to be efficient (i.e. better than O(N) on average), you could replace the bitmap with an array of integers, where the index represents the index into the view list, and the value at the index represents the index of the element in the original list.

However, unless you want `set(int, T)` to write through to the original list (or something like that), you are probably better off creating a fresh list instead of a view.

Comment: That would make `get(index)` more efficient, but `remove(index)` becomes tricky.

Comment: All changes would be very slow... which could be acceptable, maybe.

Comment: Changes that alter the number or position of elements via the view are going to be slow no matter how you do it.  That's part of the reason why you'd be better off not using a view at all.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a binary search and `Integer.bitCount` to achieve at least logarithmic time complexity in the number of bits (while your solution is in O(n)). First, 0 out half of all bits. Use `Integer.bitCount` to retrieve the number of 1's (this operation is usually mapped to a machine instruction and is therefore extremely fast). If the retrieved number is greater than your index, 0 out only half of the bytes, if it is lower, null out more (usual binary search). This will allow you to find the position in a logarithmic amount of steps.

E.g., we are looking for index 4 (i.e. the 5th element) in the two byte number `0010 1010 1110 1001`

First step:
`0010 1010 1110 1001` b = 8 > 5, null out half of all bytes

Second step: `0010 1010 0000 0000` b = 3 < 5, null out only 4 bytes

Third step: `0010 1010 1110 0000` b = 6 > 5, null out two more bytes

Fourth step: `0010 1010 1100 0000` b = 5 == 5, so the answer must lie in the remaining two bytes. Null out one more -> b = 4 -> the searched position must be the 10th byte.

Still, maintaining an index list will be faster, but will need more memory. Unless you are in an embedded setting, memory is not a too big issue and you should use this solution.

Comment: What you described works for sizes up to 64, but what would you do above?

Answer (score 0):

The efficiency of different structures will depend a lot on your access patterns. How frequent are indexed reads of the hidden list relative to number of times that visibility is changed, for example?

On average (assuming that visibility changes are either relatively infrequent or can be batched) - my suggestion would be to just create a new list which is a copy of the original list with the hidden elements removed. Reasons:

- You can build the whole thing in O(n) time, which is just O(1) per item.
- You could keep O(1) access since the new list would support direct indexed access. Scanning a bitset is O(n) which is going to be horrible for indexed access on large lists!
- You can make it immutable. Immutable things are good.

Otherwise, you will probably need to implement a custom data structure if you want to be able to switch visibility of each list item on or off at arbitrary times. Using a binary tree it would be possible to get O(log n) performance for hide, unhide and indexed lookup. I'm not aware of any existing implementations for this however - it is a bit of an unusual requirement!